# List solr replica properties

Tags: solr

I'm looking for a way to list all properties on a replica.

I checked this page: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/collections-api.html

But no such thing is mentioned there. Only adding, editing or deleting existing properties, but no way of listing all of them.

How can I find out which properties have already been set on a replica?

EDIT: Found them in zookeeper.

Use command:

```
zkCli.sh get /solr/collections/<NAME_OF_YOUR_COLLECTION>/state.json
```